# Why does Typescript type assertion not work as expected?

Tags: c#, typescript, type-assertion

Coming from C# something like this would result in compilation error:

```
interface IFoo {
    a: string
    b: string
}

interface IFoo2 {
    c: string
    d: string
    e: string
}

type FooCommon = IFoo | IFoo2

const a: IFoo = { a: 'aaa', b: 'aaa'}
const b: IFoo2 = {a: 'aaa', b: 'adfsa', c: 'adfsa'}

if((a as IFoo2) !== undefined) {
    console.log('aaa')
}
```

Whereas (a as IFoo2) actually results in simply getting back IFoo object. To me this is very confusing behavior. To make a custom typeguard I had to create something like this:

```
const isIFoo2(obj: FooCommon): obj is IFoo2 {
if (obj) {
    return 'c' in obj && 'd' in obj && 'e' in obj
  }
  return false
}
```

This works and I've seen this pattern suggested on SO and other places. It just makes me feel rather uncomfortable coming from how things work perfectly in C#.

Is the fact that TS has to transpile to JS which has no typing prevent it from having the rock-solid is/as operators that exist in C#?

Comment: *TS has to transpile to JS which has no typing* Yes, that's why

Comment: What it means is interface is not truly a 1st-class citizen in TS. Just syntactic sugar.

Comment: You'd have to make classes like in C# to compare it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=30#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8BQyRycAXMgM5hSgDmhxARuVTSPQL776iSyIoM2AEx4GRBC2p1xyACZS29YsgiKZXfGACeABxRZMAYUwBbU5hDIAvGkPIAPnZHcElqiXJCct3J%20QA5HDBAQA0yMyBwXABXG4gHpHeor5kUSHhkUFyMBQx4ZJROXmx3MAwABQVcCQUzpjCAJTIAITWtgCuIHIQMKAQcs0EKvEUmAA2EAB045i0FUEhjfgcQA),

```
if((a as IFoo2) !== undefined) {
    console.log('aaa')
}
```

is transpiled to

```
if (a !== undefined) {
    console.log('aaa');
}
```

This is expected as typings are not translated to JS. This means only JS operator will have an effect:

There are multiple ones :

- `in`
- `instanceof` (for classes)
- `typeof` (mostly for base types)